# Bang-for-buck in purchasing an instrumentation amplifier for three-electrode EEG recording?

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, eeg

While my forte has been in digital signal processing for most of my life, not-so-recently I've made the mistake of venturing into analog signal processing for a well-endowed client. I've primarily been focused on inexpensive, three-electrode EEG applications involving instrumentation amplifiers such as the INA122 ($6.22 / piece on Digikey). Now that we're moving forward to production, I'm questioning whether the INA122 is really the most cost-effective part for the job.

What are some qualities to look for in cheaper instrumentation amplifiers that might make them suitable for EEG recording? For the purposes of explanation, assume that I have three electrodes: Vin+, Vin-, and GND, The final output voltage relative to the GND electrode being some gain times Vin+ minus Vin-.

1) Gain: The thing that sticks out in cheaper instrumentation amplifiers is that the gain might be as little as 100. Previously, my INA was using only a gain of about 1,000. I'm wondering if I can continue to amplify my signal after this stage in subsequent low-pass-filter opamps safely -- what should I look for in these op-amps that would allow them to do this? Open to many suggestions /feedback here -- the EEG is actually a minor part of the circuit that has not been as well-tested as some other components.

2) Single supply vs dual supply: In the single-supply case, if Vin- is a higher voltage relative to GND than Vin+, my output will rail to 0. Then, doesn't a dual supply voltage effectively double the signal bandwidth?

3) Offset voltage: If I'm recording a microvolt signal, what's the maximum offset voltage I should look for?

I would really like an instrumentation amplifier that is about $1 but is effective in recording brainwaves. I do not need a multi-channel EEG>

Comment: Why aren't you making experimental setups, with the ability to try out ideas? These frequencies are all near DC, so there's 1/f noise but also plenty of ways to deal with that. So. Have you tried any technique used for modulation or lock-in techniques in order to move the signal out of the 1/f area? If so, what did you find? If not, why not? Noise is probably one of the significant difficulties/challenges here. (Etc.) Many of the answers you are looking for may be found in the application of good practices once you thoroughly understand the problem domain. It sounds like no research was done.

Comment: I have done a lot of research trust me, but you're right I may be procrastinating from doing more of the actual in-lab work. I guess I just wanted to see if the questions I were asking were bad questions to be asking. Part of the reason is that EEG signals are notoriously difficult to actually verify as being picked up. So you really have to go ask people who have done it before to make sure you are following best practices. Not many of these cheaper instrumentation amplifiers' datasheets will tell you X reason why they can't be used for an EEG, you know? Just trying to prevent losing time.

Comment: I suppose. I'm annoyed (were I your employer) that you hadn't pulled this research to the front. Set aside what you know and pull what you don't know to the very front and resolve those. This allows the project owner to make the earliest possible decision to kill the project, with the least loss of valuable time and money. This feels like something put towards the end that should have been at the front. I guess you were hearing my "emotional reaction" to that sense of things.

Comment: For example, you might have considered (and I'm not an expert telling you it would work) the idea of applying an oscillator to your low frequency signals, run the output through a low noise amplifier, apply a phase detector and phase adjuster relative to the oscillator, and put that through a lowpass filter to resolve your signal without the 1/f noise problem. I would have at least TRIED the idea, perhaps. Because it's commonly applied in NMR, for example. Part of the reason why is that it would allow my client to decide if the benefits might provide a market advantage worth having. Or not.

Comment: Well... I do have the oscillator already (probably the only person in the world stupid enough to try and record EEG signals beneath custom oscillations), the instrumentation amplifier is a low noise amplifier, and I have a lowpass filter. I don't have or know what a phase detector or phase adjuster is, but my curiosity is piqued, esp how the applied oscillation fits in everywhere... Also I lied I don't have a rich employer it's just me at a startup

Comment: Are you even aware of the 1/f noise in opamps? [1/f noise](http://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-048.pdf), for example? Also, is this just for yourself then? Or are you trying to muscle into some marketplace? If a marketplace, you need to know your customers and what they expect and are familiar with as well as their wish lists of new features AND ALSO how much they'd be willing to pay for each of them. Regardless, look up *choppers* and *lock-in amplifiers* and *phase locked loops* and *phase detectors* and make a study out of methods to help mitigate/remove 1/f noise.

Comment: Trivial to find despite me being a hobbyist without so much as a DC 101 class; totally ignorant of EEG: [Low Power, Low Noise Chopper Amplifier for EEG Acquisition, IEEE Journal of Solid State Circuits, Vol. 46, No. 6, April 2009](http://mgh-courses.ece.gatech.edu/ece6414/S09/Projects/Team4_FinalPaper_ECE6414_S09.pdf). This is NOT the only possible path. Lock-in and phase detection is another way. There are more. Move back to the research stage and get this right. Else your start-up dies. Seriously. I'm an *often-wrong* hobbyist with no training. Yet? I think you need to push yourself more.

Comment: I seriously want to get you off the dime, so to speak. If you are in a start-up (I secured a million dollars and started one with four partners, 30 yrs ago, and sold out when at 45 employees), your *scalable* core intellectual property is key. You need to be able to not only hold your own with others on your core IP, but stay on solid footing no matter what kind of punch comes your way. You must know your competition like the back of your hand. All of them. Not just one or two. A comprehensive view is vital. You need to own this, is all. (I spent 20 yrs doing DSP, by the way.)